# При вызове функции c Pchar на Delphi 7 возвращается `??????`

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe3

На Delphi XE3 (система Windows 8.1 x64) разработана dll, которая содержит функцию:

```
Inser(KKS: Pchar): integer;
```

При вызове этой функции с данного компьютера она работает корректно, а при её вызове с другого компьютера с системой windows 7 x64 и средой Delphi 7 параметр KKS всегда равен `??????`. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Редиректов на главную нигде нет. Проблема в том что если я напишу в адресной строке www.сайт.ru/имя_файла.php, то я все-равно попаду на главную страницу, но url при этом будет такой, который я написал.в .htaccess всего одна строка - DirectoryIndex index.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Delphi XE3 тип данных `string` соответствует `WideString`, а в Delphi 7 - `AnsiString`. Соответственно у вас происходит несовпадение типов.

Для решения, скопмилируйте DLL явно указав тип `AnsiString` или `WideString` (и соответственно `PAnsiChar` или `PWideChar`).